# Weird behavior of Terraform's random_shuffle provider

Tags: terraform

I have the following configuration:

```
variable "private_subnets" {
  default = ["subnet-A", "subnet-B"]
}

resource "random_shuffle" "az" {
  input = ["${var.private_subnets}"]
  result_count = 1
}

module "server" {
  source = "./modules/aws-ec2"
  instance_count = 3
  name = "${var.env}-server"
  stack = "server"
  role = "server"
  ami = "${lookup(var.aws_amis, var.aws_region, "")}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id = "${random_shuffle.az.result[0]}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${var.security_groups}"]
}
```

I was expecting Terraform would selected a random `subnet_id` for every instance but it's always selecting the first item in the list which is *subnet-A*. What is the best/suggested way of randomly selecting an item off a list based on the number of instances to be created?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random_shuffle` like most Terraform resources accepts the `count` parameter so if you do this like this:

```
resource "random_shuffle" "az" {
  input = ["${var.private_subnets}"]
  result_count = 1
  count = 3
}
```

It will give you 3 arrays with 1 subnet each. Accessing it will depend on how exactly you create the instances inside your module but most you're using count on `aws_instance resource` so it will be something like:

```
resource "aws_instance" "foo" {
   count = 3
   subnet_id = ${element(random_shuffle.az, count.index)}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I also found another way by computing for the modulo of the instance `count` and the length of the subnet list and using the result as the index for the subnet list.

Comment: @Francis Can't check it right now but I think `element()` wraps around so modulo is not needed.

Comment: @programming_and_math I'm pretty sure that is not the case.

Comment: @JakubKania You are indeed right. I thought it worked this way but turns out I had an error in other part of the template. I deleted my comment to not confuse people.