# Generate random value once in terraform

Tags: terraform

I have some AWS RDS databases that I want to distribute over different availability zones, this can be done like this:

```
resource "random_shuffle" "az" {
  input        = ["eu-west-1a", "eu-west-1b", "eu-west-1c"]
  result_count = 1
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "mydb" {
  availability_zone = random_shuffle.az.result[0]
}
```

The problem is that I do not want the az to ever change after the resource is created, because this would cause the resource to be destroyed.

This is a problem, because if I add/remove a item to the list a new random value will be picked.

How can I achieve this "pick a random value only once" behavior?

Comment: What are you hoping to gain by distributing individual RDS instances across different AZs instead of using the multi-AZ option?

Comment: This is for a "large" number of resource that do not need the availability (and cost) of multi-AZ, but distributing them among AZs still seems like a good idea.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49271475/weird-behavior-of-terraforms-random-shuffle-provider

Comment: If your database subnet group is spread across multiple availability zones then the RDS instances will automatically be randomly placed across them anyway.